# Define custom npm install procedure for azure/webapps-deploy@v2

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions

My project currently contains 2 apps. The first is the application Backend (NestJS) and the second is the client (VueJS).

The current folder structure follows:

- Root (NestJS)
- ./client/ (VueJS)

When I am deploying my app to Azure App Service I am using the `azure/webapps-deploy@v2` action. It's procedure is to run `npm install` in the root of the project but I need it to also run in the sub project containing the client packages. How can this be done? Are there any arguments to provide the webapps deploy action to include that addition `npm install` command?

Comment: Which platform you use ?

Comment: @JasonPan What do you mean? As in Github actions?

Comment: Which platform you use when you create azure web app?

Comment: @JasonPan NodeJS v12

Comment: Windows? Or Linux ?

Comment: @JasonPan no the platform is managed Node, not containerised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231093/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-tom-dickson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try add the commands directly in your workflow:

```
- name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
        cd ./client/mern_azure_example   # go to your client package
        npm install  # run npm install under your client package
```

But it takes very long time.

Comment: This is what I am doing at the moment, I would've thought this would work? https://pastebin.com/w2XJwxxL

Comment: It works on my side, just takes too long. But I'm not sure if you have to do the addition 
`npm install`.

Comment: When it actually deploys the webapp using the `azure/webapps-deploy@v2` action it seems to run `npm run build` again. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Actually, the `azure/webapps-deploy@v2` action just do the deploy part, not run `npm run build` command again. Have a look at this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-github-actions?tabs=applevel#deploy-to-app-service